# Cómo dar formato y agrupar columnas a un WorkSheets

Tags: c#, asp.net, interop

Quisiera que me ayuden, estoy realizando una exportación desde SQL Server hacia un Excel en C# con éxito. Solo tengo problemas que cuando genero mi excel se carga en la celda 1 pero yo quisiera que se genere en la Celda 2.

[image: Resultado del reporte]

Lo que tengo actualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código para exportar el Excel:

```
protected void btnGenerarExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string query = "SP_ReporteExcel";
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion()))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandTimeout = 90000000;
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("opt", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("fechainicio", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtFinicio.Text;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("fechafin", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtFFin.Text;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("rubro", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = dprAgencia.SelectedItem.Value;
                            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                            {
                                cmd.Connection = con;


                                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                                {
                                    sda.Fill(ds);

                                    //Set Name of DataTables.

                                    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Recibos-Energia Electrica";
                                    ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Recibos-Agua Potable";



                                    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                                    {


                                        foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                                        {



                                            wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                                            wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                                            wb.Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Black;
                                            //wb.Style.Font.FontName = "calibri";
                                            //wb.Style.Font.FontSize = 13;
                                            wb.Style.Border.DiagonalBorderColor = XLColor.Red;
                                            wb.Style.Border.RightBorderColor = XLColor.Red;
                                            wb.Style.Border.LeftBorderColor = XLColor.Red;
                                            wb.Style.Border.BottomBorderColor = XLColor.Red;

                                            var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);


                                            ws.Cells("A1:H1").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Black;
                                            ws.Cells("A1:H1").Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.Yellow;


                                           // ws.Range("D1:H1").Merge();
                                            //ws.Range("D1").Value = "Mes de ";
                                            //ws.Cells("D1:H1").Value = "Mes";

                                            //wb.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Black;
                                            //wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);



                                        }



                                        Response.Clear();
                                        Response.Buffer = true;
                                        Response.Charset = "";



                                        //sstring datetimeStringFileName = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.xls", DateTime.Now);


                                        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                                        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Reporte_Mensuales.xlsx");







                                        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                                        {
                                            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                                            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                                            Response.Flush();
                                            Response.End();
                                            Response.Redirect("FrmLogeo.aspx");
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Hola, Simplemente te escribo para que cuando subas pantallazos al menos pongas borroso los datos personales y demas informacion sensible que pueda aparecer, ya que en españa al menos existe la LOPD que hace que sea delito compartir informacion personal sin autorizacion, un saludo.

Comment: Esos pantallazos en Excel son mis datos sólo que quiero optmizimar pero no logro que saque ese formato

Comment: Disculpame si algo esta mal.

Comment: No tienes que disculparte por nada, simplemente te lo comentaba por si acaso, un saludo.

Comment: Gracias. @Veelicus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para darle color a una celda puedes utilizar el siguiente codigo

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = workbook.Worksheets.Add(dt);
ws.Cell("D1").Style.Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.Red);
```

Para insertar una fila encima de tu primera fila donde deseas colocar el titulo

```
ws.Row(1).InsertRowsAbove(1);
```

Para combinar celdas en la fila 1.

```
ws.Range("B1:D1").Merge();
```

Te recomiendo que leas la documentación.
https://closedxml.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: disculpa si me genera el excel todo okey pero cuando lo habro el excel me sale archivo dañado

Comment: Verifica a que celda le estas colocando el color.

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia como puedo verificar el color de la celda ya que no se en que lado siempre se pone ese color azul y viste ese codigo mismo lo realiza no se en donde tambien quiero poner un titulo en cabezera igual no me deja ayudame

Comment: Como puedo agrupar columnas y esa informacion que tengo quiero que se ponga en el row2

Comment: Muchas gracias enserio de verdad te agradesco.

Comment: sabes como puedo guardar en una ruta especifica porque si se descarga pero se guarda en descargas yo quiero que se guarde en Disco C